# How do I reverse argsort to point to the original unsorted array?

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

I'm annoyed with myself for not figuring this out on my own; it is most likely trivial.  But anyway, suppose I have an unsorted array, and an argsort for sorting it:

```
a = array([83, 75, 60, 80, 20,  6,  37, 81,  7, 21])
p = a.argsort()
b = a[p]
```

So the array `b` is the sorted version of array `a`.  Now I have a function which chooses certain values from a sorted list; suppose that function returns the list

```
f = [0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7]
```

These are indices for the sorted array `b`.  But how do I "invert" the sort so that I can obtain the indices which point to the corresponding values of `a`?  In this case, we have

```
b[f]
[ 6  7 20 21 75 80]
```

and the corresponding indices for `a` are

```
af = [5, 8, 4, 9, 1, 3]
```

How can I most easily determine `af` from `f`, `a` and `p`?

Comment: Have done (I think) with many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to invert anything. Remember that `p` is the index into `a` corresponding to each element of `b`. The `f`th element of `b` comes from `a` indexed with the `f`th element of `p`:

```
a[p[f]]
```

In other words,

```
af = p[f]
```

Comment: Gosh yes!  Many thanks indeed.  Well, at least I was right about it being trivial...